ASP.NET Core Web API Changing Timezone from Mobile Devices
This works fine if my web apps and API's exist on the same server but this is not the case with mobile devices.
I have users that create calendar events from their mobile devices using Flutter. When they submit to the Web API and they want the event to occur at
04/08/2024 09:30pm

When it comes to my Web API, it is changed to
04/08/2024 07:30pm

An entire 2 hours behind the time they scheduled the event for. How can I fully preserve the correct event time when it reaches the Web API? I tried converting the start and end dates to Datetime.LocalTime() but the local time is the server time. The server time is some random location.

Aren't you using UTC throughout?

I use default date = new Date(); in Flutter

Don't do that then, instead ensure you use UTC end-to-end excepting your front-end presentation layer: that's the only place where UTC values should be converted to Local/User-time.

It depends. How do you store the datetime in database? In local timezone or UTC?
One approach is to receive the datetime in UTC from mobile clients and convert it to company's timezone and store it in the database. Be careful...don't convert it in server's timezone as it could be hosted in different countries in the future.
Alternatively you can work with UTC in your API and convert it to company's timezone in your presentation layer.
In both cases you need to store company's/user's timezone.

Storing everything as default
For example Flutter date = newDate()
Web API just passes the Date to SQL Server Where it is stored>
SQL server stores whatever date and timezone the web api gives it. Web API is where the change is happening
